Multiplication of matrices with known eigenvalues
Given square matrices A and B of size $3\times 3$ with real entries, such that:
• Numbers 1, 2, and 3 are eigenvalues of matrix A,
• Numbers 4, 5, and 6 are eigenvalues of matrix B,
• The number 12 is an eigenvalue of matrix AB.
Prove that the number 12 is an eigenvalue of matrix $BA$.
I tried to write what I know such as $Ax=x$, $Ay=2y$, $Az=3z$, $Ba=4a$, $Bb=5b$, $Bc=6c$. Then I multiplied $ABm=12m$. I tried adding B by multiplying from left side $BABm=B12m$, and $BA(Bm)=B12m$. How can I finish my idea?
How can I apply this problem to find a general property for that?

Write $BA(Bm)=12(Bm)$. Since $B$ does not have zero as an eigenvalue, it follows $Bm\neq0$. So, $12$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$. I suggest you try to generalise this as much as you can.
Hope this helps. :)
